# Give me a hint or (Answer) for vector initialization

Tags: c++, vector

Im really sad that I have no idea what and how to do .
I have this,

```
struct TeamS
{
    int ID;
    string MEMBERS[3];
};

void Initialize (vector <TeamS> & TeamV, const int id[], 
     const string m[][NUM_MEMBERS], int arraySize);


int main()
{
    vector <string> TeamV;
//not sure TeamV is supposed to be int or string

const int ID[NUM_TEAMS] = { 123, 321, 456, 789 };
const string MEMBERS[NUM_TEAMS][NUM_MEMBERS] =
{
    { "Sarah", "Joe", "John" },
    { "Chris", "Kevin", "James" },
    { "Tom", "Kim", "Emily" },
    { "Jill", "Jason", "Jim" }
};

cout << "Starting Initialization" << endl;
cout << "Ending   Initialization" << endl;

}
```

I have to use this prototype
which is :

```
void Initialize (vector <TeamS> & TeamV, const int id[], 
     const string m[][NUM_MEMBERS], int arraySize);
```

to pass in the empty vector and the arrays

For example,
the first element of the vector will have team id: 123 and members: Sarah, Joe, and John.
The second element of the vector will have team id: 321 and members: Chris, Kevin, and James, and so on.

How can I do this??

DO I have to use `push_back`  ??

or is it much easier than I think??

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make TeamV a vector of type TeamS, so each element in TeamV can contain information about a team (ID and MEMBERS). Using the push_back() method is sounds like a great idea, try it out

Answer (score 0):

`vector <string> TeamV;` ==> This has to be '`vector<TeamS> TeamV;`'

To add elements to vector, first you need to construct individual entries.
Something like:

```
TeamV.push_back(TeamS());
TeamV[0].ID = id[0];
std::copy(m[0], m[0] + NUM_MEMBERS, TeamV[0].MEMBERS);
```